# How to show git user in terminal (oh-my-zsh)

Tags: git, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm having a blast with oh-my-zsh and enjoying the [spaceship prompt](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt).

[image]

Just like it is showing my git branch and status - how can I make it show my current git user right next to that?

(The reason for asking is because I'm doing [pair coding](https://github.com/pivotal-legacy/git_scripts) and it would therefore be useful info)

Comment: your question is really about `git` not anything else, this functionality is not the default in a simple repo without anything fancy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow you @Michael

Comment: I don't think you can get the user, in the `git log` command there are many options but they all relate to the commit. I don't see anything with the user (you can get the committer details).  
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: I would expect to do `git config user.name` and somehow display that in the terminal - the same way it's displaying if I have unstaged files etc

Comment: I don't see that as an option in the docs but maybe I missed something

Comment: As someone who has just recently switched to ZSH... I cam here for a completely different reason so thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing a custom section for spaceship-prompt.

```
spaceship_git_user() {
  spaceship::is_git || return

  local username

  username="$(git config user.name)"

  if [[ -n $username ]]; then
    spaceship::section \
      "magenta" \
      "$username"
  fi
}
```

Then, add the custom section into spaceship prompt.

```sh
SPACESHIP_PROMPT_ORDER=(
  # content omitted ...

  git_user

  # content omitted ...
)
```

Put these two parts into your `.zshrc` before your prompt (spaceship) is initialized.

References

- [customize spaceship with `SPACESHIP_PROMPT_ORDER`](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt/blob/master/docs/Options.md#order)

Comment: Thank you so much @Simba - this was exactly what I was looking for!