# zsh shell diplay ruby version and ruby gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, rvm, oh-my-zsh

I am using Oh-my-zsh with Gallois theme.
Many years ago I configured myzsh to show: git branch - ruby version@gemset like this:

[image]

I am configurin my new development virtual machine, I installed Oh-my-zsh shell with Gallois theme but I can't find the line to edit to obtain the images configuration

How can I edit the zsh or gallois theme to show the current branch and the rubyversion@rubygemset ?

Comment: Why does this has a _bash_ tag? There is no bash involved in your question.

Comment: becouse I don'r remember if it is a bash customization or a zsh customization?=

Comment: You are mentioning oh-my-zsh! How can this possibly be a bash customization????

Comment: In your opinion where can be the customization? I searched a lot but i don t find it

Comment: AFIK, there is no equivalent to _oh-my-zsh_, if you run bash. May I suggest that you switch to zsh? In this case, the customizations for the interactive use of the shell go into ~/.zshrc. See the section called _INVOCATION_ in the zsh man page.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766085/how-to-show-git-user-in-terminal-oh-my-zsh) helps. If you intend to modify a oh-my-zsh theme to your own taste, perhaps you first study [here](https://ohmyz.sh/) a bit. I presonally don't use oh-my-zsh, but configure my prompt manually.

Comment: You will need th [git plugin](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git) for oh-my-zsh.